# Ferramenta para trabalhar em grupo

Tags: ftp

Galera temos um problema aqui no escritório que é utilizar um arquivo que o colega ja esta usando, e salvar e assim perder o arquivo, alguém conhece alguma solução? utilizamos Brackets e Sublime text se for algum plugin ajuda muito!

Comment: 5 anos atrás estava iniciando não sabia bem como me expressar.

Hoje sei o que precisava na época e realmente não existia.

A funcionalidade que eu precisava era algo parecido com o que vemos hoje no [Live Share do VSCode](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara se estiver trabalhando com desenvolvimento, recomendo você versionar seus projetos.

Voce pode utilizar o Git pra isso, onde cada funcionario podera editar o mesmo arquivo e salvar versoes diferentes: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-No%C3%A7%C3%B5es-B%C3%A1sicas-de-Git

Answer (score 0):

Olha, ao ler sua pergunta eu achei estranha essa situação. Como vc diz que vcs desenvolvem web em equipe e não compreendem um processo simples como esse ?

Mesmo que vcs não usassem um controle de versionamento que seria o ideal, pelo menos entender que, não se edita arquivos remotamente se vc precisa manter o arquivo aberto por longos períodos como é o cso de atividades de desenvolvimento. Pq se a máquina remota der algum problema vc não está vendo o que está acontecendo. Imagine que a máquina remota receba um pico de energia e reinicie. Vc não poderá salvar seu trabalho e mesmo que isso não ocorra outra pessoa que abra o mesmo arquivo, conflitará com o seu. O mínimo seria copiar o arquivo remoto para sua máquina e enviar no final da edição com o custo de outra pessoa ter enviado antes e poder perder o arquivo dela. Como acabou acontecendo.

Mas o certo não é assim. O certo para desenvolvimento em grupo é usar um sistema de controle de versionamento como por exemplo o Git que o tkmattos mencionou. Eu tbém recomendo o Git. Ele é excelente. Mas existem mais como o CVS, Subversion, Mercury e outros.

Sistemas de controle de versionamento funcionam assim: vc cria um repositório e cada pessoa envia 'modificações' àquele repositório. Ex.: inicialmente vc coloca no repositório o index.htm, index.css e index.js. Aí um desenvolvedor inclui uma regra no index.css e envia ao repositório. O controle de versionamento permite não só ver a versão atual, como todas as modificações feitas como identificar quem fez, como ver versões passadas do projeto todo e muito mais.

Alguns têm ainda funções mais avançadas como a criação de "ramos". Funciona assim: vc vai desenvolver uma resolução de bug. Aí vc cria um ramo separado do desenvolvimento enquanto o resto da equipe continua trabalhando no ramo principal. Vc terá então todas as funções de histórico e versionamento em um ramo separado sem confundir com o resto da equipe. Então quando e se sua versão estiver toda ok, vc "funde" seu ramo ao ramo principal de desenvolvimento.

O Git permite ainda a criação de repositórios locais, que depois enviam suas mudanças a um repositório central, entre muitas outras funções que seria longo demais descrever em uma resposta como essa.

Como pode ver esse tipo de tecnologia é essencial para desenvolvimento em grupo. Vc pode utilizar todas essas funções apenas em linha de comando. E é bom que saiba bem a linha de comando. Mas recomendo que vc utilize uma IDE que permita a integração completa de todas essas funções. A que eu posso recomendar é a que eu uso: Eclipse. Poucos softwares são mais completos que ele. Talvez só o VIM (mas aí também é covardia, o VIM não é um software é uma experiência :D).

Ele também tem um plug-in que é um must para desenvolvimento em grupo. O Mylyn. Ele se conecta a um repositório de tarefas e guarda o histórico dos arquivos que foram abertos para cada tarefa realizada. Assim, se vc concluir uma tarefa e depois vc ou alguém da sua equipe precisar refazer alguma coisa referente a essa tarefa vc tem todos os arquivos que foram alterados por quem realizou o serviço em 1o lugar. Prático né ?

Além dos excelentes links que o tkmattos passou que já são ótimos pra vc aprender Git quero passar esse de um jogo muito legal pra aprender git que me passaram esses dias:

http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/?demo